# Problems with apt-get and <package>:i386 naming

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit

I am trying to build a package for a 32-bit app. on a 64-bit machine running 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04. The build was successful, the app runs correctly, I have also created a .deb for it using debhelper, but when it comes to actually install it, surprise:

```
# apt-get install nd-tcms-agent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  nd-tcms-agent:i386 : Depends: lib32gcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: lib32stdc++6:i386 (>= 4.4.0) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libc6-i386:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Did I mention that my code built successfully? And it wouldn't have had, were those libraries not installed!

Now, here's what I did:

```
# apt-cache showpkg lib32gcc1:i386
Package: lib32gcc1:i386
Versions:

Reverse Depends:
  nd-tcms-agent:i386,lib32gcc1:i386 1:4.1.1
Dependencies:
Provides:
Reverse Provides:
```

Where'd that go? I swear it was here a minute ago...

Guess what?!? It was hiding behind the `:i386` suffix:

```
# apt-cache showpkg lib32gcc1
Package: lib32gcc1
Versions:
1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 (/var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language:
             File: /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
              MD5: a31c67d540f86442c895f2663cb4d5c9
 Description Language: de
             File: /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-de
              MD5: a31c67d540f86442c895f2663cb4d5c9
 Description Language: en
             File: /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
              MD5: a31c67d540f86442c895f2663cb4d5c9

1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language:
             File: /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
              MD5: a31c67d540f86442c895f2663cb4d5c9
 Description Language: de
             File: /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-de
              MD5: a31c67d540f86442c895f2663cb4d5c9
 Description Language: en
             File: /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: a31c67d540f86442c895f2663cb4d5c9


Reverse Depends:
  nvidia-352-updates,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-352,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-340-updates,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-340,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-304-updates,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-304,lib32gcc1
  fglrx-updates-core,lib32gcc1
  fglrx-core,lib32gcc1
  libx32go5,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  libx32gcc-4.8-dev,lib32gcc1 1:4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
  lib32stdc++6-4.8-dbg,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32stdc++6,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32objc4,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32go5,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32go4,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32gfortran3,lib32gcc1 1:4.4.0
  lib32gcc1-dbg,lib32gcc1 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4
  lib32gcc-4.8-dev,lib32gcc1 1:4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
  lib32asan0,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  brother-lpr-drivers-extra,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32stdc++6-4.6-dbg,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32stdc++6-4.4-dbg,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32objc3,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32go0,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  gcc-4.6-multilib,lib32gcc1 1:4.6.4-6ubuntu2
  gcc-4.4-multilib,lib32gcc1 1:4.4.7-8ubuntu1
  nvidia-331-updates,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-331,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-304-updates,lib32gcc1
  nvidia-304,lib32gcc1
  fglrx-updates,lib32gcc1
  fglrx,lib32gcc1
  libx32go5,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  libx32gcc-4.8-dev,lib32gcc1 1:4.8.2-19ubuntu1
  libx32gcc-4.7-dev,lib32gcc1 1:4.7.3-12ubuntu1
  lib32stdc++6-4.8-dbg,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32stdc++6-4.7-dbg,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32stdc++6,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32objc4,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32go5,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32go4,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
  lib32gfortran3,lib32gcc1 1:4.4.0
  lib32gcc1-dbg,lib32gcc1 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1
  lib32gcc-4.8-dev,lib32gcc1 1:4.8.2-19ubuntu1
  lib32gcc-4.7-dev,lib32gcc1 1:4.7.3-12ubuntu1
  lib32asan0,lib32gcc1 1:4.1.1
Dependencies:
1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 - gcc-4.9-base (5 4.9.3-0ubuntu4) libc6-i386 (2 2.2.4)
1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 - gcc-4.9-base (5 4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1) libc6-i386 (2 2.2.4)
Provides:
1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 -
1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 -
Reverse Provides:
```

You should also know that I did not add those `Depends:` to my package by hand. `debhelper` did. And I know this may not be directly your problem, but if you happen to know who the guy that had the marvellous idea to add the : suffix to "foreign" packages is, please rub his nose in this, while I'm looking for a workaround!

Or, it may just be that I am getting this mixed-arch thing totally wrong...

Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

And here comes my workaround (I do believe this to be a workaround, and not a solution!):

This is how my package's control info looked originally:

```
$ dpkg -I ../nd-tcms-agent_1.1-1_i386.deb
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 248492 bytes: control archive=624 bytes.
     410 bytes,    10 lines      control
     315 bytes,     4 lines      md5sums
 Package: nd-tcms-agent
 Version: 1.1-1
 Architecture: i386
 Maintainer: my@email-address.com
 Installed-Size: 929
 Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.4.0), libc6-i386 (>= 2.17), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libzmq3 (>= 3.2.3+dfsg)
 Section: utils
 Priority: optional
 Homepage: [...]
 Description: [...]
```

I stress: the `Depends:` in there were added to it by `debhelper`, based on info it collected itself during building the package.

So, what I did was to try to override them myself, by adding a `debian/shlibs.local` file:

```
libgcc_s                1       libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
libstdc++               6       libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0)
libm                    6       libc6 (>= 2.17)
libpthread              0       libc6 (>= 2.17)
libc                    6       libc6 (>= 2.17)
```

(I won't go into the details of what's in there, there's plenty of info about that online and in the manuals)

And now, my package's control info reads:

```
$ dpkg -I ../nd-tcms-agent_1.1-1_i386.deb
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 248320 bytes: control archive=620 bytes.
      401 bytes,    10 lines      control
      315 bytes,     4 lines      md5sums
  Package: nd-tcms-agent
  Version: 1.1-1
  Architecture: i386
  Maintainer: my@email-address.com
  Installed-Size: 929
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0), libzmq3 (>= 3.2.3+dfsg)
  Section: utils
  Priority: optional
  Homepage: [...]
  Description: [...]
```

Now, if all the dependencies from the libs mentioned in the debian/shlibs.local are actually resolved correctly based on the correct arch, or not, is left for your/mine best guess (maybe I could have just put anyhting in there that resolved to a package that has a :i386 variant -- that's why I consider this to be a workaround, and not a solution!); what's certain is that now my package does install (and yours will, too, probably, if you had faced the same problem)...

Cheers!